# Is hyper ledger fabric considered as centralized blochain

Tags: hyperledger, centralized, decentralized-applications

Hyper ledger has some classic/old world mechanisms that brings up the question, is it really decentralized?

Having a REST **server** to communicate with the blockchain brings up the cloud model behavior.

Even though the hyper ledger is distributed, someone calling a rest API will may be written to the server logs with some data such as IP address, GEO info and more.

So, is hyper ledger fabric considered as centralized blockchain or maybe decentralized blockchain?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you mean decentralised as in not controlled by any one entity and anonymous then no, it is not that.

Fabric is the backbone of blockchain applications and certain things are plug and play. it is not meant to be anonymous, it is meant to be controlled and only known parties have access to anything.

It's simply an eco-system which allows anyone to build blockchain based applications. Imagine a system where your bank holds your money and you want to pay someone. The bank needs to make sure that you are who you say you are and no one else can authorise payments from your account. That's what the permissions mean. It's not meant to bypass the man in the middle like bitcoin or other cryptocurrencies are. Those however are just an implementation of a block chain system, they are not the only way you can use such a system though.

The immutability of the ledger offers certain advantages. Imagine an audit system where every action is recorded and can't be changed. If your audit records are  in a sql database for example, anyone with access can go in, change or delete that data. What goes on the ledger stays there for ever and can't be change. This doesn't mean that your asset data cannot change. That is a fundamental thing to understand. Underlying data can be changed via a new transaction against the same asset, but the history of the asset is clearly visible and can't be modified.

In this world, you build a something, someone controls it, gives access to other organisations and people within those and every action has its source identified.

It is decentralised in the sense that the ledger does not live in one place only, a copy of the ledger exists on every peer that is joined to a channel.

However, it is not meant to be anonymous, all the participants are known and their access level controlled, that's the whole point.